# Improved current mirror

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, cmos

The picure below is a improved current mirror. There are two equal input currents Iin and an output Iout. M1 converts Iin into BIASN2 to bias transistor M4B and M3A converts Iin into BIASN to bias transistor M4A.

So what is the role of transistor M3B here? It is a cascoded transistor and by adding it, the output impedance increases. However, I don't see why we want to increase output impedance at this branch.

[image]

Comment: What is the output impedance of an ideal current source (or sink as in this case)?

Comment: It is not clear but I assumed it is infinity.

Comment: So the higher the impedance the closer to ideal, no?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. I thought that you asked for the output impedance of input current Iin. For your question above, an ideal current source has infinite output resistance. However, what I don't understand is the branch with transistor M3B. This branch is not a current source. It is only to create bias voltages for the current source on the right. So what is the role of transistor M3B here?

Comment: I think to generate  BIASN2.

Comment: BIASN2 is generated by M1 transistor only.

Comment: Right, so rather it is BIASN, based on BIASN2. I don't think the high Z is the goal- it is symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

The transistor M1 will generate the bias voltage for the cascoded current source and has no other function.

The following schematic illustrates the point:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd7HOp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In order to have accurate current mirroring, you would want to have:

1. The same \$V_{GS}\$, as is the case with all current mirrors
2. The same \$V_{DS}\$, which is only the case on the right
3. Matching transistors (layout level)

Adding M3B will improve point 2, by also working on the drain of M5 (M3A in your reference image).